# calculating F1 score in Excel

Tags: excel

In statistics

if you predict a value 1 and the original value was 1 then this is called True Positive (TP)

if the prediction is 0 and the original value was 1 then it is False Negative (FN)

if the prediction is 1 and the original value was 0 then it is False Positive (FP)

if the prediction is 0 and the original value was 0 then it is True Negative (TN)

F1 score is a method to measure the relation between 2 datasets

Which is calculated like this

[image]

I have a file that has the results of 1000+ predictions
each value is either 0 or 1

that looks like this

```
Label    0    1    2   ....   0    1    2    ...   
--------------------------------------------------
         0    0    1          0    1    1   
         1    0    0          1    0    1   
         0    1    1          0    0    0   
         0    0    1          0    1    1   
         1    0    0          0    0    0   
         1    0    1          0    1    1   
         0    0    1          1    0    1   
         1    1    1          1    1    0   
         0    1    0          1    0    1   
         1    1    0          0    0    1   
         1    0    0          0    1    0   
         1    1    0          1    1    1   
         0    1    1          1    0    1   
         0    0    1          0    1    1   
         0    1    0          1    0    0   
         1    1    0          0    1    0   
         0    1    1          1    1    1   
         0    0    0          1    0    0   
         0    0    1          0    1    1   
         0    1    1          1    0    0
```

The only way I can think of having a 1000+ new columns to detect TP and another to detect FP and anorger 1000 for TN and another 1000 for FN

where each has this equation =if(AND(B6=NB6,B6=1), 1, 0) for TP and so on

this is not a good solution

is there a faster easier way to get F1 score for each one of these columns or even better F1 score micro and macro for all?

Comment: Could you add a bit of explanation / references plz? I don't know what is meant by F1,TP, FP FN or TN.

Comment: i explained that in my question

Comment: Should your data be interpreted such that the left `0, 1, 2, ...` are predictions and the right `0, 1, 2, ...` are the corresponding original values? **Side Note:** your proposed formula is the same as `=B6*NB6`. If both cells are 1, `1 * 1 = 1`. Otherwise `0 * <0 or 1> = 0`.

Comment: @MarkBalhoff yes the left side 0,1,2,.. are the original values and the right side 0,1,2,.. are the predictions.. you cant use B6*NB6 because you will miss the values of TN, FN, FP they all will be 0

Comment: If these are independent measures then it's still a lot of columns to compare, but you should be able to use countifs or a sumproduct formula to do the calculation on a whole pair of columns at one go

Comment: My point wasn't to solve the rest of the problem. It was to simplify your starting point. The formula I gave is a simpler formula for TP and fits well into `SUMPRODUCT`. As @TomSharpe said, SUMPRODUCT can give you trivial, single-cell formulas for TP, FP, TN, and FN sample set counts. From there you can do the rest of your calculations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not going to finish this tonight, but I think the formulas for columns B and E of the test data would be

Precision:

```
=COUNTIFS(B2:B21,1,E2:E21,1)/(COUNTIFS(B2:B21,1,E2:E21,1)+COUNTIFS(B2:B21,0,E2:E21,1))
```

Recall

```
=COUNTIFS(B2:B21,1,E2:E21,1)/(COUNTIFS(B2:B21,1,E2:E21,1)+COUNTIFS(B2:B21,1,E2:E21,0))
```

and you can get the others in the same way

[image]

**EDIT**

For clarity, I would suggest using named ranges. These ranges would be anchored to a particular set of rows which could be dynamic, but would refer to a different column as they are pulled across something like this

[image]

Then you could use formulas like this for TP

```
=COUNTIFS(Original,1,Prediction,1)
```

and

```
=TP/(TP+FP)
```

for precision.

[image]